# spotify api "player/currently-playing" enpoint is not return currently playing song data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to get data about a song playing on one of my devices from the spotify API. I have created a view that fetches data from the API and part of it looks like this:

```
class Song(viewsets.ModelViewSets):
    ....
        room_code = request.data['room_code']
        room = Room.objects.filter(code=room_code)[0]
        host = room.host
        endpoint = 'player/currently-playing'
        response = execute_spotify_api_request(host, endpoint)
        
        item = response.get('item')
        duration = item.get('duration_ms')
        progress = response.get('progress_ms')
        album_cover = item.get('album').get('images')[0].get('url')

        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The `execute_spotify_api_request(host, endpoint)` is a utility function and it looks like this:

```
def execute_spotify_api_request(session_id, endpoint, post_=False, put_=False):
    tokens = get_user_tokens(session_id)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': "Bearer " + tokens.access_token}
    if post_:
        post(BASE_URL + endpoint, headers=headers)
    if put_:
        post(BASE_URL + endpoint, headers=headers)
    response = get(BASE_URL, {}, headers=headers)
    try:
        return response.json()
    except:
        return {'error': 'Could not retrieve a response'}
```

The full url from which im fetching is ""https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"

The problem is with the response that im getting from the API, the response is not an error but data that im not expecting to get. Im getting a response that looks like this:

```
response = {
    "display_name": "Tanatswamanyakara",
    "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/dlnsysel6bndktbvduz6cl79w"
    },
    "followers": {
        "href": null,
        "total": 0
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/dlnsysel6bndktbvduz6cl79w",
    "id": "dlnsysel6bndktbvduz6cl79w",
    "images": [],
    "type": "user",
    "uri": "spotify:user:dlnsysel6bndktbvduz6cl79w"
}
```

I was hoping to get data (the progress, title, duration, album, artist etc) about the song I am playing on my spotify account but instead I get that response, how do I fix that?

**N.B
My access tokens and refresh tokens are working as they should. (so I think)**

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not what you are expecting then there's going to be something wrong with your API endpoint. You can use the Spotify developer console to generate the endpoint link, it would be worth debugging your `execute_spotify_api_request` code and the url it generates against the value in the console.

Having just re-read your code half way through answering, I've noticed that you aren't appending your `endpoint` variable to your GET url:

```
response = get(BASE_URL, {}, headers=headers)
```

This means that the get doesn't have `'player/currently-playing'` and just returns the base URL which is probably `'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/'` - hence the response you receive is just your profile data.